# Как столбец датафрейма из формата строки со временем ('hh:mm:ss') привести к типу целых чисел (например все перевести в минуты или секунды) на Python

Tags: python, строки, pandas, время

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Мне нужно написать функцию, которая принимает на вход 3 значения: table(датафрейм, состоящий из 7 столбцов, одним из которых является столбец 'time', в котором записаны данные типа object, по факту это строка вида 'hh:mm:ss'), time1 (строка вида 'hh:mm'), time2(строка вида 'hh:mm'). Функция должна вернуть датафрейм, который получится из исходного путем сортировки по столбцу 'time'. Это означает что в новом датафрейме будут только те строки, в которых значения столбца 'time' удовлетворяют следующему условию: time1 <= time <= time2. Как привести данные time1, time, time2 к единому виду, чтобы фильтрацию можно было сделать с помощью логической индексации? Я понимаю каким образом можно перевести в минуты time1 и time2, но совсем не могу понять как быть со столбцом time (секунды можно отбросить и перевести все в минуты). Данную задачу скорее всего можно решить средствами обычного Python и модуля pandas, тк никаких особых модулей для работы со временем предварительно не изучалось.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строковые значения вида `hh:mm:ss` можно привести к типу данных `timedelta` и после этого получить общее число секунд:

```
df["seconds"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["time"]).dt.total_seconds()
```

Comment: Извините, получилась такая ошибка: /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:23: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: @ДенисВишневецкий Извините, но никто не знает, что вы делаете. Если вы думаете, что отвечающий  стоит у вас за спиной и смотрит через ваше плечо, что у вас на мониторе, то увы, это не так.  Вы почему-то проигнорировали комментарий под вопросом, можно узнать причину? PS: решение в ответе я проверил, у меня работает.